# How to summarize a dynamic range in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that would sum up a dynamic range of numbers in two columns.

The problem I am facing is that the data I am exporting never has the same amount of rows, therefore defining a set range, as G1-G10 for example, is pointless.

I've tried several codes found on stack overflow but none seems to work.

Note: The data always starts in G1 and H1.

Ideally the summarized columns needs to be in bold format with "all borders".

Hopefully someone can help!

The code I currently have, that obviously is not going to work, is this;

```
Sub HGFHGH()
Range("G1:H21").Select
Range("G21").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-20]C:R[-1]C)"
Range("G1:H21").Select
Range("H21").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-20]C:R[-1]C)"
Range("G21:H21").Select
Range("H21").Activate
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Range("I20").Select
End Sub
```

Best regards,

Tor

Comment: https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-last-row/

Comment: But how can I make this work so that the number it produces (the summary) ends up as below the last non blank cell?

Comment: In other words, how can I make define the point "D2" in your article, as a dynamic position rather than a fixed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to take a look on the forums for finding the last row in vba- this is a very common task that you'll learn to either memorize or know where to go to copy it in the future!

Note in my code swap out the 7 for which ever column you want the last row count to be based off of, most keep it as 1 for column A, I don't know if you have data there, so I put 7 for column G.

```
Dim Lrow As Integer
Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G1:H" & Lrow).Select
```

Take note of the process: I'm declaring a variable called Lrow, assigning the row count to it, and then using Lrow instead of hardcoding a row like you did. eg: H21 vs "H" & Lrow.

If you needed to enter a formula in the next blank row, you would then have something like below, where I'm totaling only column G, and putting the answer in the next row. (Lrow +1)

```
Range("G" & Lrow + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("G1:G" & Lrow))
```

Comment: Perfect!

I tried different variations of the "lastrow, "lowrow" code but did not get it to work, but this worked perfectly!

Any suggestions as to be able to make the numbers bold and with borders also? This would also be a dynamic position, same as the summary.

Thanks for the help, much appriciated Perry!

Comment: Without looking too closely at the rest of the code where you're doing the formatting, I'd give this a quick try:  Where you have Range("G21:H21").Select - I would swap that out with Range("G" & lrow+1 & ":H" & lrow +1).Select and see how that looks.

Comment: After your first comment I changed the original code to this;
    Dim Lrow As Integer
    Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G1:H" & Lrow).Select
    Range("G" & Lrow + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("G1:G" & Lrow))
    Range("H" & Lrow + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H1:H" & Lrow))

Should I add this to format the cells;
 Range("G" & Lrow + 1 & ":H" & Lrow + 1).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
?

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

It looked quite bad as a comment so I'll write it as an answer.

The code Perry Moen gave me resulted in the summary being dynamic and working perfectly.

So now my code for summarizing the columns looks like this;

```
Dim Lrow As Integer
Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G1:H" & Lrow).Select
Range("G" & Lrow + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("G1:G" & Lrow))
Range("H" & Lrow + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H1:H" & Lrow))
```

Now I am trying to make the result from above code formatted to be bold and with "all borders".

```
Range("G" & Lrow + 1 & ":H" & Lrow + 1).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Range("I20").Select
End Sub
```

It dawned on me that I need to "activate the cells" in order to apply the formatting. It it possible to change "Range("G21").Activate" to just "Range("G").Activate?

Thanks a lot for the help!